# Commas before and after therefore?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is it correct to use commas around therefore in the following quote?

> An important prerequisite to meet the requirements of ... is, therefore, the ability to ...

Or should I omit the first comma to make the sentence correct?

> An important prerequisite to meet the requirements of ... is therefore, the ability to ...

Answer (score 3):

You can either not use commas at all

> is therefore the ability to...

Or use commas before and after:

> is, therefore, the ability to...

The commas are parenthetical, which can often be omitted when the interruption is brief, as in this example, but you should never use a comma before a parenthetical phrase and not after it (or vice versa).

See [the section on parenthetical commas here](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html) to learn more.